# the best schema for a django model with relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-1.8

I have a model User and a model Team. 
Often I use all fields of Team and one field (username) of User but not always !

A Team contains many users, for these relation I create this model (1) :

```
class joinTeam(models.Model):
    username_user=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Projet, null=False)
```

But I hesitate to replace this field 'username_user' by this (2):

```
 class joinTeam(models.Model):
    username_user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Projet, null=False)

I'm afraid that this model (2) consumes more capacity the the first (1).
```

**How use a simple CharField or a ForeignKey ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm afraid that this model (2) consumes more capacity the the first
>   (1).

Don't be afraid, django will store just a reference(pointer/id) to the user, not the whole model instance.

You model should looks like this:

```
class joinTeam(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Projet, null=False)
```

Rename `username_user` to `user`.

Also, is good practice, trying to not duplicate data, if you store `username` in `joinTeam table`, you are duplicating data, because, you can obtain it from `user table`.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to use the sample two, with the foreingKeys.

> best practices, rename the user_name_user to user
>   and by default, null = False, but if you wants, can explicit it

```
class joinTeam(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Projet)
```

When making queries, just use the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), you will just take a hit in the database.

```
joinTeam.objects.all().select_related('user')
```